# PDF certification signature invalidates multiple approval signatures with ITextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I'm using ITextSharp 5.1.1 to digitally sign a PDF with multiple signature fields.  I have 4 signature fields: 3 approval signatures (users sign the document) and the 4th signature is the certification signature, which our system signs to indicate that the document is verified as correct and that no further modification can be made to the PDF.

If I add multiple approval signatures, a new revision is created for each signature and all the signatures are valid.

As soon as I then add the certification signature at the end of the signing process, it invalidates all the previous approval signatures.

Am I missing something here? Is there a different way to achieve the same effect as the certification signature without invalidating the approval signatures?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is to first add a number of approval signatures to a document and afterwards a certification signature.

This approach cannot work because it violates the PDF specification. As the question is from 2011, I quote from part 1, i.e. ISO 32000-1 published 2008, and not part 2, i.e. ISO 32000-2 published 2017; in essence both specifications agree on this issue, though.

> A PDF document may contain the following standard types of signatures:
>
> - One or more approval signatures. [...]
> - At most one certification signature (PDF 1.5). [...] The signature dictionary shall contain a signature reference dictionary (see Table 253) that has a **DocMDP** transform method. See 12.8.2.2, “DocMDP” for information on how these signatures shall be created and validated.
> - At most two usage rights signatures. [...]

*(ISO 32000-1 section 12.8 "Digital Signatures", subsection 12.8.1 "General")*

> The **DocMDP** transform method shall be used to detect modifications relative to a signature field that is signed by the author of a document (the person applying the first signature). A document can contain only one signature field that contains a **DocMDP** transform method; <kbd>it shall be the first signed field in the document.</kbd>

*(ISO 32000-1 section 12.8.2.2 "DocMDP", subsection 12.8.2.2.1 "General")*

Thus, it is no wonder that *as soon as you then add the certification signature at the end of the signing process, it invalidates all the previous approval signatures,* because adding a certification signature to an already signed document by definition makes the signature structure of the document invalid. (Ok, Adobe's error message in this case could more clearly point out the issue...)

---

You wonder *is there a different way to achieve the same effect as the certification signature without invalidating the approval signatures?*

According to ***raw ISO 32000-1*** your options are limited. By means of a *signature field lock dictionary* (see section 12.7.4.5 "Signature Fields") and a **FieldMDP** transformation in your final signature you can lock existing form fields:

> On behalf of a document author creating a document containing both form fields and signatures the following shall be supported by conforming writers:
>
> - The author specifies that form fields shall be filled in without invalidating the approval or certification signature. The **P** entry of the **DocMDP** transform parameters dictionary shall be set to either 2 or 3 (see Table 254).
> - The author can also specify that after a specific recipient has signed the document, any modifications to specific form fields shall invalidate that recipient’s signature. There shall be a separate signature field for each designated recipient, each having an associated signature field lock dictionary (see Table 233) specifying the form fields that shall be locked for that user.
> - When the recipient signs the field, the signature, signature reference, and transform parameters dictionaries shall be created. The **Action** and **Fields** entries in the transform parameters dictionary shall be copied from the corresponding fields in the signature field lock dictionary.

*(ISO 32000-1 section 12.8.2.4 "FieldMDP")*

But if your original certification signature allowed annotation changes or there is no certification signature to start with, you cannot dis-allow such annotation changes.

If, on the other hand, your PDF processors and viewers support ***ISO 32000-1 plus the Adobe Supplement with ExtensionLevel 3***, an additional entry in the *signature field lock dictionary* is specified:

> **P** number *(Optional; ExtensionLevel 3)* The access permissions granted for this document. Valid values follow:
>
> 1, no changes to the document are permitted; any change to the document invalidates the signature.
>
> 2, permitted changes are filling in forms, instantiating page templates, and signing; other changes invalidate the signature.
>
> 3, permitted changes are the same as for 2, as well as annotation creation, deletion, and modification; other changes invalidate the signature.
>
> Default value: none; absence of this key results in no effect on signature validation rules.
>
> If MDP permission is already in effect from an earlier incremental save section or the original part of the document, the number shall specify permissions less than or equal to the permissions already in effect based on signatures earlier in the document. That is, permissions can be denied but not added. If the number specifies greater permissions than an MDP value already in effect, the new number is ignored.
>
> If the document does not have an author signature, the initial permissions in effect are those based on the number 3.
>
> The new permission applies to any incremental changes to the document following the signature of which this key is part.

*(Adobe Supplement to ISO 32000-1 ExtensionLevel 3 part I "Extensions to the PDF specification", section 8.6.3 "Field Types", subsection "Signature Fields")*

This addition has been adopted by ***ISO 32000-2***.

---

If you want to make use of these mechanisms using iText since version 5.3.0, have a look at the [Digital Signatures for PDF Documents](https://developers.itextpdf.com/books#digsig) whitepaper by Bruno Lowagie, iText. Section 2.5.5 "Locking fields and documents after signing" illustrates how to use those mechanisms with iText.